# Printing Entity Framework Linq query as a string

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I would like to be able to log long running entity framework linq queries so I can investigate what is being generated. I have found that having an Entity Framework linq query and if I hover my mouse over it in the Visual Studio debugger, it shows me a string representation of the generated SQL that the entity framework will send to the SQL server.

I am wondering how it would be possible to get this string so I could print it out to a log file?

Comment: you also can use Linqpad, which supports to generate sql from your dbcontext

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you try `ToString()`;

```
var query = context.Products.Where(p=>p.IsActive);
var queryText = query.ToString();
```

Comment: Wow... no I had not! I had read that it didn't work, though that was for an earlier version of the framework than what I am using. That should work perfectly - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this [logging provider for Entity Framework](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/EFProviderWrappers-c0b88f32)